# Type checking of optional nested properties in an interface

Tags: typescript

I want to perform type checking on nested properties in an interface, and have the following code

```
type PathImpl<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends string
  ? T[K] extends Record<string, any>
    ? `${K}.${Path<T[K]>}` | K
    : K
  : never;

export type Path<T> = PathImpl<T, keyof T>;

export interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  dimensions: {
    height: number;
    weight: number;  
  }
  address?: {
    street: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
  };
}

const validPath: Path<User> = 'name'; // Works fine
const alsoValidPath: Path<User> = 'address'; // Works fine
const nestedValidPath: Path<User> = 'dimensions.height'; // Yay, works fine!
const doesntWorkPath: Path<User> = 'address.street'; // Doesn't work because address is optional
```

Is there a way to design the Path type to also allow 'address.street' to be valid, although address is optional?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgSQLZgDYB4AqAaKAaSggA9gIA7AEwGcoBrCEAewDMocA+KAXiJLkqdKLWAAnAJaUA5gCgoUAPycA2oQC6gijXoAlCAGMW46ljFTZBOJRBcFi5VAAGAEgDehAL4A6D-CRcdQ0uL2coAB8iB0UALmi4qEoIADcIcQBuOTkyMBNgKFBIWAREXB5+AJR0bHxGZnZOLiyc0jzxAukKcTY4Q2gAVVp0qHcHSjhUCHiLaRksxTgZaaSAV1QAI3SFqGpJKcpaSRZD+LHHKEQISRlEYHjKda3MmKgAd2vb+7XN7cUHLwOODUajiCC0WhKM6vCwQCDfWayHaKQySUAzCRzZGiYAIFaI+YArKAuTGQ4FFJwDCSahVeJVLBDdIVKAAcgmU1ZGSgAHoeVAAOomBj0NjSCCkk5iKBU2gsABqVJpdJKgSZ4hZrOBoPBtC5vP5QvEIqgYuSkvJSXBFGoiuptNK9NKjOGGr4bL2ByOUp8Vxud31fKgAE04CACG9haLxQBCC3S6gscGUYBGhgqhnqzXasEQnyw+GB-kAESTtEorIKkeNUC2hjgq2GMpBufoknoLDAwGOEwwQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) utility type in `Path` to mark all properties on the input type as required:

```typescript
export type Path<T> = PathImpl<Required<T>, keyof T>;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then your final assignment with `"address.street"` is valid because the type of `Path<User>` is:

```
| "name" 
| "age" 
| "dimensions" 
| "address" 
| "dimensions.height" 
| "dimensions.weight" 
| "address.street" 
| "address.city" 
| "address.state"
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgSQLZgDYB4AqAaKAaSggA9gIA7AEwGcoBrCEAewDMocA+KAXiJLkqdKLWAAnAJaUA5gCgoUAPycA2oQC6gijXoAlCAGMW46ljFTZBOJRBcFi5VAAGAEgDehAL4A6D-CRcdQ0uL2coAB8iB0UALmi4qEoIADcIcQBuOTkyMBNgKFBIWAREXB5+AJR0bAMARwBXSXEIM24CJlYObiyc0jzxAukKcTY4Q2gAVVp0qHcHSjhUCHiLaRksxTgZFaSG1AAjdM2oakllylpJFkv4+ccoRAhJGURgeMp9o8yYqAB3Z6vd57Q7HRQOLwOODUagtWi0JR3X4WCAQYFrWQnRSGSSgVYSdZY0TABC7DEbCFZSFyYyXAopOAYSTUKrxKpYabpCpQADki2WPIyUAA9MKoAB1EwMehsaQQGk3MRQRm0FgANUZzNZJUCnPE3J50NhEHhgpFYsl4mlUFlyQVdKSJoo1A1TJZpTZpQ5M31fF5ZwuV0VPieLzeZtFUAAmnAQAQ-lKZXKAIT2pXUFgmyjAS0MbXsvUGo1w2g+FFoiMWxNJFh-IA)